# using Task.FromResult to create async wrappers around sync functions?

Tags: c#, async-await

i'm going through a [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc) in the asp.net vnext series. I came across something in the [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc) that doesn't make a lot of sense:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using TodoList.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TodoList.ViewComponents
{
    public class PriorityListViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

        public PriorityListViewComponent(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        // Synchronous Invoke removed.

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int maxPriority, bool isDone)
        {
            string MyView = "Default";

            // If asking for all completed tasks, render with the "PVC" view.
            if (maxPriority > 3 && isDone == true)
            {
                MyView = "PVC";
            }

            var items = await GetItemsAsync(maxPriority, isDone);

            return View(MyView, items);
        }

        private Task<IQueryable<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync(int maxPriority, bool isDone)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(GetItems(maxPriority, isDone));

        }
        private IQueryable<TodoItem> GetItems(int maxPriority, bool isDone)
        {
            var items = db.TodoItems.Where(x => x.IsDone == isDone &&
                                                x.Priority <= maxPriority);

            string msg = "Priority <= " + maxPriority.ToString() +
                         " && isDone == " + isDone.ToString();
            ViewBag.PriorityMessage = msg;

            return items;
        }

    }
}
```

They are creating a wrapper for a sync method and just calling `Task.FromResults()` so its async. First of all its still going to block so whats the point? Probably behind the scenes its just creating a `TaskCompletionSource` & wrapping the results in `Task` object. They then `await` the results which probably just is creating extra overhead that is not needed i would think. The db call they are making through EF is still sync. Am i missing something here or is a bad example?

Comment: have you read up on `await, Task, and async` to understand when and why async is used..? just curious based on the last few statements in your question..

Comment: @DJKRAZe I have but maybe my i don't have some of the concepts grasped. Primarily its used in UI apps so you don't block the ui thread and in web apps so you don't consume precious thread resources while your doing IO type work. In the example i don't see what it buys you.

Comment: @DJKRAZE can you point out where you think i'm confused? I don't think i am.

Comment: `private Task<IQueryable<TodoItem>>` I would make that method static personally also you do not have the `asycn` defined in your method for example `public static async Task<IQueryable<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync`

Comment: @DJKRAZE this is not my code. This is the code from the example (from microsoft)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bad example. It serves no value to create an async wrapper around a synchronous operation and such a decision should usually be left to the library consumer.

> I believe the only asynchronous methods that should be exposed are those that have scalability benefits over their synchronous counterparts.  Asynchronous methods should not be exposed purely for the purpose of offloading: such benefits can easily be achieved by the consumer of synchronous methods

From [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)

And while there are times when it's appropriate (like complying with a `Task` returning interface or abstract method) this doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

You're quite right that it's just going to end up blocking, and that making everything have an asynchronous API but with synchronous behavior is only going to perform [slightly] worse.

As for why you'd do it; you'd do it so that it exposes an identical API to the *actually* asynchronous versions, allowing both implementations to meet an interface or other type of contract allowing them to be used by a caller that doesn't know which implementation is actually being used.  It is likely being used here as a stop gap while the application is transitioning to being entirely asynchronous, but to which certain pieces do not yet have asynchronous implementations.  When you upgrade your database provider and have *actually* asynchronous versions of these methods it'll mean you only need to change this implementation, and won't need to change anything on the caller's side of things.

Of course, it has its fair share of potential problems if you end up with a caller expecting a method like this to actually behave asynchronously and not block for a long period of time, given that it doesn't do that at all.

This is a hack; not one without purpose, but you *do* need to recognize it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with I3arnon: It serves no purpose but to confuse the consumer of this code.

The example isn't implementing any common interface, so Servy's argument about exposing an identical API doesn't feel right in this case.

The method stub:

```
private Task<IQueryable<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync(int maxPriority, bool isDone) { .. }
```

explicitly declares that it not only returns a task (which does not necessarily imply asynchronicity), but by its very name, that it *is* async.

As for increased overhead, the only unnecessary action that is performed here is the creation of a Task object. No async / TPL code is executed. To that end, I'd say this example is simply misleading.

If this was *my* code, I'd assume I had been in a rush, and expect to see a

```
// TODO: Make this async!
```

comment in that method ;)